# Implement a VBA program on excel to filter the graph with a lot of values at once (without tiking each box with the classic filter tool)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with a lot of references and every day I have to do a Vlookup to find the relevant in formation. So I am looking for a program where I only have to do a copy paste of the references that I am looking for and it would filter the table. I have more than a 100 references to filter at once.

I tried using the "autofilter contains" but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I could do ?

kind regards,

Comment: This question is either kind of unspecific or lacking in information, thus hard to give a direct answer to. If the Vlookup is already there, why is it a problem? In what whay did the "autofilter contains" not work? Are you trying to filter 100 columns at once in a single table? If so, is it the same or different criterias? Present some example data with expected outcome and a specific question, and you will get help faster.

Comment: For example, I have an excel sheet with 10 columns. My first column is the product reference (the criteria I want to filter). I would like to implement a program where I can filter that first column with for example 100 different product references by doing a copy/paste of the references I what to appear (So imagine I have 10000 lines it will only show the 100 lines that interest me). The "autofilter contains" seems to only work with 1 product reference. Is it clearer ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you want to sort the table (one column) with multiple criteria, correct? What do you mean by copy/paste?

Comment: Yes that's it ! Well several time per week I receive a list of products that I need to check the info that is in the excel sheet (the sheet I want to filter). So I would like to put in place a program where I copy the list of products that I received during the week and paste it in the excel so it filters the table and shows only the lines regarding the products that I received.

Comment: I am not very good at programing but I found something on internet. Sub FILTERREFERENCE()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("000022")
        .Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & .Range("I2:I10000").Value & "*"
    End With
 
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2010/12/15/excel-autofilter-with-criteria-in-a-range/

```
Sub DoMyFilter()
    
    Dim vCrit As Variant
    Dim aCrit As Variant
    
    vCrit = Range("H1:H5").Value
    aCrit = Application.Transpose(vCrit)
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$7634").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=aCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```